# Struggling to get a smooth movement with rotate, transform origin and transform duration in CSS

Tags: css, rotation, transform

I've got some problems with CSS rotate and transform-origin. I have the words "video credits", and when the user clicks on them, I want them to slowly rotate 90 degrees clock-wise (sort of nicely fall down) and then end up vertically.
The words ends in the perfect position, but the trajectory is very weird. The words sort of jump very far to the top right and then suddenly move to the final position. I have been playing around with it for ages, but can't manage to make them nicely fall down the way I want to. It keeps jumping around in random ways. Could anyone help? Here's the CSS and jQuery.

```
#video-credits {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 7;
    padding-top: 3rem;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
}

#video-credits.active {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    color: var(--color-blue);
    transform-origin: 0.6rem 4rem;
    transition-duration: 1s;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#video-credits").click(function(){
        $("#video-credits").toggleClass("active");
    });
});
```

I recreated it here. It does a similar thing here in jsfiddle as on my website, but on the website it somehow jumps way further up.

https://jsfiddle.net/of6mqkxL/13/

It would be great if someone knows what's going on. Thanks!

Comment: This may be a similar problem to the one here [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66547970/css-zoom-into-specific-image-point/66552504?noredirect=1#comment117666001_66552504 in that you get more smoothness on Firefox in your example than in Edge/Chrome. Try putting the transform and transform-origin into keyframes rather than transition and see if it makes things smoother.

Comment: Ah nice thanks so much! That sounds like a similar problem indeed! I will have a look and see it this can help me, thanks!